# PHP large number into SQL

Tags: php, sql, int, long-integer

I'm trying to use this query:

```
$cert= 125125161241261241261;
$cert= $cert + 1;
INSERT into table (column) values ($cert);
```

however, when the insertion is done.

I get something like `12512516124126124+E17` or something like that.
I already have put the datatype into `varchar(max)` and `var_dump`'ed my variable

SQL Server 200x.

Comment: have you try putting the variable with quotes to indicate is  a string instead a number ?

Comment: Is this too big to be saved in an `INTEGER` field?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes I did, did not work..

Comment: @RocketHazmat apparently yes, I tried it and it returned Couldn't execute query.

Comment: Show us how are you calling the insert method? Are you creating parameter or you using dynamic sql?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Just a normal insertion simple query.

Comment: Can you show me your code?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza `$query   = $sql->Query("INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3,certificate,col4,col5) 
   values('$val1','$val2','$val3','".$new_cert."','$val4','$val5')"); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a SQL procedure that does the insert and used it in my PHP insertion, Thanks for whoever tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

Insert quotes `'`

```
$cert= 125125161241261241261;
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES('".$cert."'");
                                                       ^^^       ^^^ 
                                                         INSERT QUOTES.
```

**BEWARE OF SQL [INJECTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**

USE this way

```
$cert= 125125161241261241261;
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES(?)";

$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $cert); -- 's' indicate is a string parameter

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: apparently this variable is already set and is not based on user input, and already filtered to be is_numeric() so no worries about SQL injection, I use OOP for queries too. however, can you please explain to me how a single quoted double quote differ from only a single quote?

Comment: double quotes `"` indicate a php string. single quotes `'` inside the php string indicate to sql that is a `string`. So is diferent `"insert (5)" vs "insert ('5')"`. First insert number second insert string. That is why you get your big number convert to scientific notation.

Comment: That's such a useful information I will always keep in mind. I thought that there's no difference between " ' " and " " ' " " and they were alternatives to each other, thanks for the useful tip!

Comment: Remember upvote / accept answer if this solve your issue :)

Comment: `$query   = $sql->Query("INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3,certificate,col4,col5) 
   values('$val1','$val2','$val3','".$new_cert."','$val4','$val5')");`

Comment: You didnt concate the strings.  Use `'.`$val`.'` Also as I suggest create a `$sql` variable instead. So you can debug the `$sql` value before pass to the `QUERY` function

Comment: I forgot to say, that after assigning the variable I add a +1 each time. I tried removed that line and it was successfully inserted..any ideas?

Comment: What difference that make? I told you to show me your $sql value

Comment: What do you mean by "my $sql value"?

Comment: I told you create a variable $sql and save the query string there. You really need to read more

Comment: Can't you see that $sql variable is my oop main class?

Comment: Then create a variable $strSQL